# Discover historical trends in Elasticsearch (not visual)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some experience with Elastic as logs storage, but I'm stuck on basic trends recognition (where I need to compare found documents to each other) over time periods.

Easy query would answer following question:

*Find all occurrences of document rows (row is specified by growing/continues @timestamp value), where specific field (e.g. threads_count) is growing for fixed count of documents, or time period.*

- So if I have thread_count of some application, logged every minute over a day including timestamp. And I specify that I'm looking for growing trend in 10 minutes - result should return documents or document sets where thread_count was greater over the one from document minute before at least for 10 documents.

**It is very similar task to see line graph, and identify growing parts by eye.**

Maybe I just miss proper function name for search. I'm not interested in visualization, I would like to search similar situations over the API and take needed actions.

Any reference to documentation or simple example is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Well script cannot be used between documents. So you will have to use a payload.

In your query sort the result by date.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/6.3/how-watcher-works.html

A script in the payload could tell you if a field is increasing (something like that, don't have access to a es index right now)

```
"transform": {
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx.payload.transform = []; def current_score = -1;
def current = []; for (int j=0;j<ctx.payload.hits.hits;j++){
//check in the loop if current_score increasing using ctx.payload.hits.hits[j]._source.message], if not return "FALSE"

 } ; return "TRUE",
    "lang": "painless"
    }
}
```

If you use logstash to index your documents, take a look to elapsed, could be nice too: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html

Comment: If I understand well, transforms by scripts are only possible in definition of watchers, what are only available in non free X-Pack part, what is currently not possible for me to subscribe in current phase of project. I'm I right?

Comment: Should be the best solution indeed. It should be possible to do it using aggregation, group documents you want to compare and you could create a custom outer buckets with script (but it will be really, really complicated script and result would be hard to  parse).

Comment: Thank you for details, for research purpose I will go with some small java service, for analyze. Later I will have to learn a little about x-pack features. Thanks!